# Библиотеки для обнаружения движения на экране

Tags: c++

Существуют ли библиотеки, с помощью которых можно отслеживать движущиеся на экране объекты?

Comment: сравнивать два кадра? opencv?

Comment: @KoVadim то что на экране компьютера в реальном времени

Comment: opencv и вперед.

Comment: @KoVadim каким метоом?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129253/screen-capture-with-opencv-and-python-2-7 - захват картинки с рабочего стола, http://www.robindavid.fr/opencv-tutorial/motion-detection-with-opencv.html - детектирование изменений

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, не подумал просто сравнивать 2 картинки, думал, что есть специальные библиотеки для этого